# Update multiple rows with corresponding values from another table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, import-from-csv

Using MySQL, I'm working on a script that will import data from a CSV file. I've gotten to the point where the script is finished for importing data for a single user, however that I want to extend to all users now. A statement I currently have is the following:

```
UPDATE werte 
    SET werte=(SELECT Date_Enrollment 
               FROM THKON01.data 
               WHERE auto_patient_id = 1020)
    WHERE folder_id = 1525 
    AND number=4;
```

Now what I want is to use the enrollment dates from all users (so I would omit the "WHERE auto_patient_id ..." statement) and insert them into all corresponding rows. Here lies the problem. I tried for two users at once with the statement

```
UPDATE werte 
    SET werte=(SELECT Date_Enrollment 
               FROM THKON01.data 
               WHERE auto_patient_id = 1020
                   OR auto_patient_id = 1051)
    WHERE folder_id between 1524 AND 1525 
    AND number=4;
```

However this gave me an error that said "Query returned multiple rows", referring to the inner query of SELECT Date_Enrollment.
Note that the auto_patient_id's are not sequentially numbered, so I can't use a "between" there.

EDIT: For clarification

I have two tables. One, werte, is where I want the values to be stored to. THKON01.data is the table I want to read the values from. In case of this example, I want the Date_Enrollment values to be written into the werte table. Let's say I have 3 users I want to do this for, then the structure for THKON01.data looks like this:

```
auto_patient_id    Date_Enrollment
1020               01.01.1911
1050               02.01.1912
1073               03.01.1913
...                ...
```

Now I want to insert this into the werte table which looks like this:

```
folder_id    werte
1525         <empty>
1526         <empty>
1527         <empty>
...          ...
```

I want them to be inserted so that the first value of THKON01.data (01.01.1911) gets copied to the first value in werte (field of folder_id 1525), the second (02.01.1912) gets to the second (folder_id 1526), and so forth. Folder_id is sequentially numbered, auto_patient_id is not. I hope that clarifies this a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some links between fields `auto_patient_id` and `folder_id` you can try something like this

```
UPDATE werte 
SET werte=(SELECT Date_Enrollment 
           FROM THKON01.data 
           WHERE (your_link))
WHERE number=4;
```

here `your_link` can be of `THKON01.data.auto_patient_id = werte.somefield` or `THKON01.data.auto_patient_id = somefunction(werte.folder_id)`

It will select only one record at a time and update all your records that fall under outer where condition.

**update**

if you want to use some bash script you can use smth like this

```
$folder_id = 1 # or some other start number
mysql -e "SELECT Date_Enrollment FROM THKON01.data" | while read Date_Enrollment; do
   mysql -e "update werte set werte = $Date_Enrollment where folder_id = $folder_id"
   $folder_id = $folder_id + 1
done
```

You said that your folder id are in order, so we can just add 1 each time instead of fetching them from result.

I'm absolutely not proficient with bash scripting so this script could be not working, but I hope that the idea is clear.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no links between fields in those tables. THKON01.data is basically just a table that I created from a .csv imported file, so I can then insert the data into my table that is used by my application. This sub-step is necessary because I can't just import the data 1:1 from the .csv.

Comment: Then how do you define which record should be modified with which one? f.e. in your first example result from `where auto_patient_id=1020` should be written in record with `folder_id=1525 and number=4`. How do you calculate this dependence? Can you automate it with some SQL formula? If yes, you have a solution, if no, you, unfortunately, have to loop thru all your records and modify them one by one with appropriate conditions.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to figure out - how to link these two. In theory, the values of auto_patient_id and folder_id are irrelevant, the first field of the former corresponds to the first field of the latter, second to the second, tenth to the tenth, and so on. I am trying to figure out how to take each Date_Enrollment from THKON01.data to my werte entry.

Comment: if these values are irrelevant, then how do you decide where should you write each value? Maybe there is some table or rule which links auto_patient_id with folder_id? or maybe you'll post some more info about your tables structure and we''l figure out how to link these values? :)

Comment: Edited the OP for clarification. I don't need to cross-link or anything, the first value goes to the first row, second to the second, and so on.

Comment: I see. Another question - what if you will use not only mysql functionality in your script? If it is OK you could fetch all records from 1st table, then all from second table and construct each update statement in the loop, moving thru 2 received recordsets. It could be a bit slow, but you don't run database updates often.

Comment: Hm I see what you mean. Any concrete idea on how to go about this? Do you mean just write an eg. bash script that does this?

Comment: I'm updated the answer, but I'm not proficient with bash scripts so the script could be not working. But anyway I hope that idea is clear.

Comment: Okay I got the idea! Thanks a lot.